# SVG inside HTML doesn't apply basic CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

Trying to make a basic map with hovering areas - using SVG.

I cant understand why SVG (inside html) isn't reacting to basic CSS, tried hovering paths, then just changing color - but none work. I cant find why. 
SVG elements react only if the code is applied directly in html style.

```css
     .p1-pos {max-width: 50rem; margin: auto}
       
      path {fill: rgb(93, 93, 131)}
      path:hover {fill: bisque}
```

```html
     <div class="p1-pos">
        <svg
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
        xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
        viewBox="0 0 184.13573 153.7863"
        version="1.1"
        id="svg8"
        inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
        sodipodi:docname="ten.svg">
       <defs
          id="defs2" />
       <sodipodi:namedview
          id="base"
          pagecolor="#ffffff"
          bordercolor="#666666"
          borderopacity="1.0"
          inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
          inkscape:pageshadow="2"
          inkscape:zoom="0.35"
          inkscape:cx="353.68731"
          inkscape:cy="296.33408"
          inkscape:document-units="px"
          inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
          showgrid="false"
          fit-margin-top="0"
          fit-margin-left="0"
          fit-margin-right="0"
          fit-margin-bottom="0"
          units="px"
          inkscape:window-width="993"
          inkscape:window-height="727"
          inkscape:window-x="2239"
          inkscape:window-y="83"
          inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
       <g
          inkscape:label="Layer 1"
          inkscape:groupmode="layer"
          id="layer1"
          transform="translate(-12.253565,-73.452084)">
         <g
            transform="translate(-3.4347496,-8.6454107)"
            id="layer1-1"
            inkscape:label="Layer 1">
           <path
              style="fill:none;stroke:#101010;stroke-width:2.79112649;stroke-miterlimit:10"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              stroke-miterlimit="10"
              d="m 29.637126,160.10752 c -2.014139,-3.34132 -4.07245,-3.76035 -4.229412,-6.0628 -0.156934,-2.30245 -1.48781,-4.06796 -2.976562,-5.52587 -1.488753,-1.45791 -0.468996,-1.07478 -2.270722,-2.91675 -1.801733,-1.84194 -5.24729,-2.83936 -1.17484,-4.6813 4.072454,-1.84197 8.85075,-3.30079 11.591408,-5.2192 2.740656,-1.9184 3.524505,-3.22341 5.169276,-2.6865 1.644771,0.53691 3.759477,3.60745 9.55565,4.29821 5.79617,0.69074 11.278423,0.84457 15.585846,-0.99741 4.307419,-1.84198 8.615773,-4.52846 13.158175,-4.45109 4.54238,0.0773 12.375238,1.7655 16.05578,0.92097 3.68051,-0.84451 8.92969,-4.98895 11.827305,-5.83347 2.89761,-0.84453 9.24267,-0.38314 11.20042,-2.3789 1.95775,-1.99574 7.51897,-5.67964 7.51897,-5.67964 0,0 2.4286,-2.07222 3.68145,-3.37724 1.25286,-1.30506 3.99445,-5.06539 5.87416,-6.90734 1.87976,-1.84194 3.68054,-4.37465 3.68054,-6.75355 0,-2.378849 3.68149,-7.213996 6.26612,-8.212356 2.58461,-0.998309 8.06782,-1.151183 10.26054,-2.839351 2.19273,-1.688169 3.2886,-2.302429 3.75855,-4.220837 0.46993,-1.918408 4.38541,-2.840324 6.81403,-1.305043 2.42864,1.535269 7.59696,0.153887 10.10362,0.767174 2.50662,0.613366 6.89299,3.377232 12.06227,0.997452 5.16928,-2.379833 4.46437,-3.377246 7.04901,-3.530108 2.58464,-0.152757 6.65803,0.613353 7.59788,3.760334 0.93989,3.146967 1.48691,6.830909 -3.36845,9.670272 -4.85538,2.839379 -7.67499,5.833473 -10.02466,6.830893 -2.3497,0.99738 -9.86862,1.9184 -10.96545,5.14181 -1.09684,3.22342 -1.40886,5.44943 -4.77736,7.21403 -3.3685,1.76458 -8.53776,7.29137 -10.26057,9.74671 -1.72278,2.45534 -2.50566,2.83937 -5.95216,4.14438 -3.44652,1.30506 -6.65805,2.68651 -7.83287,7.52163 -1.17486,4.83517 -1.72371,6.83091 -0.70492,8.97954 1.01882,2.14862 2.03576,3.83772 1.40982,6.29304 -0.62595,2.45533 -5.48321,5.75611 -5.6392,8.05855 -0.15598,2.30246 -3.05364,8.21146 -4.62039,11.51222 -1.56678,3.30079 -5.63923,8.28879 -5.7962,12.66346 -0.15693,4.37465 0.54793,10.36191 -2.50663,13.20127 -3.05458,2.8394 -12.53128,14.27425 -15.11593,16.73049 -2.58462,2.45627 -7.44092,7.21406 -8.77177,9.28625 -1.33085,2.07218 -3.289555,2.37888 -8.223855,2.53267 -4.934322,0.15388 -8.14585,0.69076 -11.435389,3.22342 -3.289553,2.5327 -3.05457,2.07224 -5.326249,2.226 -2.271666,0.15389 -4.229413,0.61338 -6.65709,1.91841 -2.42768,1.30502 -5.091273,-1.53435 -5.247292,-2.91581 -0.155982,-1.38148 0.391935,-7.44426 -0.704889,-9.2098 -1.096843,-1.76549 -5.795242,-1.68905 -5.952196,-5.60321 -0.156973,-3.91417 0.391923,-4.37375 -5.247292,-10.05339 -5.639212,-5.6797 -10.80849,-10.59034 -11.043459,-14.12137 -0.234983,-3.53101 -2.506632,-7.21402 -4.542385,-8.97954 -2.035759,-1.7655 -4.307421,-5.67965 -3.994443,-8.44259 0.312989,-2.76293 2.506627,-7.06206 0.469931,-9.28716 -2.036695,-2.22505 -4.309295,-3.75848 -5.328116,-5.44756 z"
              id="path20" />
        <a xlink:href="http://svgtutorial.com/styling-svg-with-css/">
           <path
              sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccccsccccccccc"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              id="path42"
              d="m 21.069671,142.60696 8.744703,-2.69068 4.93291,-3.36335 4.26024,2.46646 5.157133,1.34534 9.417372,0.89689 7.175141,-0.89689 11.211157,-4.93291 13.677614,1.12111 6.950919,-0.67267 10.09004,-4.70868 20.40431,4.93291 c 0,0 -69.060736,63.9036 -69.957628,63.9036 -0.896893,0 -6.278248,-6.7267 -6.278248,-6.7267 l -2.242232,-7.17514 -5.605578,-7.39936 -1.345339,-3.36335 1.121115,-8.29626 -3.363347,-5.38135 -6.950918,-7.84782 -3.363347,-7.62358 z"
              style="fill:#ffccaa;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
        </a>
           <path
              sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccccccccccscccc"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              id="path44"
              d="m 60.757172,197.54164 65.159788,-59.83247 13.99099,11.40026 2.018,3.81179 -3.58757,2.46646 -1.79378,5.60558 -4.26024,10.76271 -5.15713,7.84781 -1.12112,4.03602 -0.22422,10.76271 -23.99188,25.78566 -1.34534,2.01801 -7.175141,1.56956 -6.950919,0.67267 -6.054024,4.03602 -5.605579,0.44845 -3.363348,1.56956 h -1.121117 c 0,0 -0.672668,-9.6416 -1.121113,-10.76271 -0.448448,-1.12112 -5.605582,-3.58757 -5.605582,-3.58757 l -1.121114,-6.05403 -6.726696,-7.84781 z"
              style="fill:#ffccaa;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
           <path
              sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              id="path46"
              d="m 108.56809,130.60168 16.43433,3.5916 6.817,4.33877 8.0516,7.09367 2.04559,-11.71675 3.5829,-5.23655 7.71702,-2.75607 9.37065,-10.19748 6.61459,-3.85851 1.92925,-7.44141 11.57552,-3.8585 11.57552,-7.992626 -1.10243,-4.68533 -1.65364,-0.826823 -6.61459,3.307292 -6.61458,0.826823 -6.89019,-1.653646 h -6.06337 l -7.1658,-1.653646 h -0.55121 l -3.85851,4.68533 -10.47309,4.409722 v 0 l -4.73981,2.135419 -0.77707,5.588685 -6.6079,7.92007 -10.99554,11.06377 z"
              style="fill:#ffccaa;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
         </g>
       </g>
     </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have inline styles in your svg

Comment: Indeed - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/PoYGxpW - A Good SVG optimiser will remove all that unnecessary inkscape cr@p.

Comment: @bartc because if you use inline css, there is a chance that an external css won't work as it used to be. You can use `!important` for that in your css but that is not a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to change the fills, just remove them from the html source and do wath you want in the css code like this.

```css
.p1-pos {max-width: 50rem; margin: auto}
       
      path {fill: rgb(93, 93, 131)}
      path:hover {fill: bisque}
```

```html
<div class="p1-pos">
        <svg
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
        xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
        viewBox="0 0 184.13573 153.7863"
        version="1.1"
        id="svg8"
        inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
        sodipodi:docname="ten.svg">
       <defs
          id="defs2" />
       <sodipodi:namedview
          id="base"
          pagecolor="#ffffff"
          bordercolor="#666666"
          borderopacity="1.0"
          inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
          inkscape:pageshadow="2"
          inkscape:zoom="0.35"
          inkscape:cx="353.68731"
          inkscape:cy="296.33408"
          inkscape:document-units="px"
          inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
          showgrid="false"
          fit-margin-top="0"
          fit-margin-left="0"
          fit-margin-right="0"
          fit-margin-bottom="0"
          units="px"
          inkscape:window-width="993"
          inkscape:window-height="727"
          inkscape:window-x="2239"
          inkscape:window-y="83"
          inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
       <g
          inkscape:label="Layer 1"
          inkscape:groupmode="layer"
          id="layer1"
          transform="translate(-12.253565,-73.452084)">
         <g
            transform="translate(-3.4347496,-8.6454107)"
            id="layer1-1"
            inkscape:label="Layer 1">
           <path
              style="fill:none;stroke:#101010;stroke-width:2.79112649;stroke-miterlimit:10"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              stroke-miterlimit="10"
              d="m 29.637126,160.10752 c -2.014139,-3.34132 -4.07245,-3.76035 -4.229412,-6.0628 -0.156934,-2.30245 -1.48781,-4.06796 -2.976562,-5.52587 -1.488753,-1.45791 -0.468996,-1.07478 -2.270722,-2.91675 -1.801733,-1.84194 -5.24729,-2.83936 -1.17484,-4.6813 4.072454,-1.84197 8.85075,-3.30079 11.591408,-5.2192 2.740656,-1.9184 3.524505,-3.22341 5.169276,-2.6865 1.644771,0.53691 3.759477,3.60745 9.55565,4.29821 5.79617,0.69074 11.278423,0.84457 15.585846,-0.99741 4.307419,-1.84198 8.615773,-4.52846 13.158175,-4.45109 4.54238,0.0773 12.375238,1.7655 16.05578,0.92097 3.68051,-0.84451 8.92969,-4.98895 11.827305,-5.83347 2.89761,-0.84453 9.24267,-0.38314 11.20042,-2.3789 1.95775,-1.99574 7.51897,-5.67964 7.51897,-5.67964 0,0 2.4286,-2.07222 3.68145,-3.37724 1.25286,-1.30506 3.99445,-5.06539 5.87416,-6.90734 1.87976,-1.84194 3.68054,-4.37465 3.68054,-6.75355 0,-2.378849 3.68149,-7.213996 6.26612,-8.212356 2.58461,-0.998309 8.06782,-1.151183 10.26054,-2.839351 2.19273,-1.688169 3.2886,-2.302429 3.75855,-4.220837 0.46993,-1.918408 4.38541,-2.840324 6.81403,-1.305043 2.42864,1.535269 7.59696,0.153887 10.10362,0.767174 2.50662,0.613366 6.89299,3.377232 12.06227,0.997452 5.16928,-2.379833 4.46437,-3.377246 7.04901,-3.530108 2.58464,-0.152757 6.65803,0.613353 7.59788,3.760334 0.93989,3.146967 1.48691,6.830909 -3.36845,9.670272 -4.85538,2.839379 -7.67499,5.833473 -10.02466,6.830893 -2.3497,0.99738 -9.86862,1.9184 -10.96545,5.14181 -1.09684,3.22342 -1.40886,5.44943 -4.77736,7.21403 -3.3685,1.76458 -8.53776,7.29137 -10.26057,9.74671 -1.72278,2.45534 -2.50566,2.83937 -5.95216,4.14438 -3.44652,1.30506 -6.65805,2.68651 -7.83287,7.52163 -1.17486,4.83517 -1.72371,6.83091 -0.70492,8.97954 1.01882,2.14862 2.03576,3.83772 1.40982,6.29304 -0.62595,2.45533 -5.48321,5.75611 -5.6392,8.05855 -0.15598,2.30246 -3.05364,8.21146 -4.62039,11.51222 -1.56678,3.30079 -5.63923,8.28879 -5.7962,12.66346 -0.15693,4.37465 0.54793,10.36191 -2.50663,13.20127 -3.05458,2.8394 -12.53128,14.27425 -15.11593,16.73049 -2.58462,2.45627 -7.44092,7.21406 -8.77177,9.28625 -1.33085,2.07218 -3.289555,2.37888 -8.223855,2.53267 -4.934322,0.15388 -8.14585,0.69076 -11.435389,3.22342 -3.289553,2.5327 -3.05457,2.07224 -5.326249,2.226 -2.271666,0.15389 -4.229413,0.61338 -6.65709,1.91841 -2.42768,1.30502 -5.091273,-1.53435 -5.247292,-2.91581 -0.155982,-1.38148 0.391935,-7.44426 -0.704889,-9.2098 -1.096843,-1.76549 -5.795242,-1.68905 -5.952196,-5.60321 -0.156973,-3.91417 0.391923,-4.37375 -5.247292,-10.05339 -5.639212,-5.6797 -10.80849,-10.59034 -11.043459,-14.12137 -0.234983,-3.53101 -2.506632,-7.21402 -4.542385,-8.97954 -2.035759,-1.7655 -4.307421,-5.67965 -3.994443,-8.44259 0.312989,-2.76293 2.506627,-7.06206 0.469931,-9.28716 -2.036695,-2.22505 -4.309295,-3.75848 -5.328116,-5.44756 z"
              id="path20" />
        <a xlink:href="http://svgtutorial.com/styling-svg-with-css/">
           <path
              sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccccsccccccccc"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              id="path42"
              d="m 21.069671,142.60696 8.744703,-2.69068 4.93291,-3.36335 4.26024,2.46646 5.157133,1.34534 9.417372,0.89689 7.175141,-0.89689 11.211157,-4.93291 13.677614,1.12111 6.950919,-0.67267 10.09004,-4.70868 20.40431,4.93291 c 0,0 -69.060736,63.9036 -69.957628,63.9036 -0.896893,0 -6.278248,-6.7267 -6.278248,-6.7267 l -2.242232,-7.17514 -5.605578,-7.39936 -1.345339,-3.36335 1.121115,-8.29626 -3.363347,-5.38135 -6.950918,-7.84782 -3.363347,-7.62358 z"
              style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
        </a>
           <path
              sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccccccccccscccc"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              id="path44"
              d="m 60.757172,197.54164 65.159788,-59.83247 13.99099,11.40026 2.018,3.81179 -3.58757,2.46646 -1.79378,5.60558 -4.26024,10.76271 -5.15713,7.84781 -1.12112,4.03602 -0.22422,10.76271 -23.99188,25.78566 -1.34534,2.01801 -7.175141,1.56956 -6.950919,0.67267 -6.054024,4.03602 -5.605579,0.44845 -3.363348,1.56956 h -1.121117 c 0,0 -0.672668,-9.6416 -1.121113,-10.76271 -0.448448,-1.12112 -5.605582,-3.58757 -5.605582,-3.58757 l -1.121114,-6.05403 -6.726696,-7.84781 z"
              style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
           <path
              sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              id="path46"
              d="m 108.56809,130.60168 16.43433,3.5916 6.817,4.33877 8.0516,7.09367 2.04559,-11.71675 3.5829,-5.23655 7.71702,-2.75607 9.37065,-10.19748 6.61459,-3.85851 1.92925,-7.44141 11.57552,-3.8585 11.57552,-7.992626 -1.10243,-4.68533 -1.65364,-0.826823 -6.61459,3.307292 -6.61458,0.826823 -6.89019,-1.653646 h -6.06337 l -7.1658,-1.653646 h -0.55121 l -3.85851,4.68533 -10.47309,4.409722 v 0 l -4.73981,2.135419 -0.77707,5.588685 -6.6079,7.92007 -10.99554,11.06377 z"
              style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
         </g>
       </g>
     </svg>
    </div>
```